# can not install from usb with error cannot find grub_platform

Tags: grub2

Laptop: HP Compaq 6710b

I burned a new 20.10 usb and started the install from the usb. The "can not find grub_platform" message appears then a menu displays where I select UBUNTU. The next screen is just a blinking cursor.

Within the usb I found the grub.cfg file where there is a grub_platform entry. Is this where the error is coming from? How do fix it?

Thanks;

Sherman

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue where grub loads up, very quickly displays the same grub_platform error, I click "Try or install Ubuntu" then goes to blank screen with cursor. But my USB drive is already MBR! Any ideas what else could cause this? [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh0X6.png

Answer (score 13):

After creating a bootable pen drive, you have to convert it to MBR. Insert the pen drive and use Gparted to find out whether the pen drive is detected as `sdb` or `sdc` etc. For this explanation, I'm assuming `sdb`.

`sudo gdisk /dev/sdb`
Enter `r` for transformation.
Enter `g` for converting GPT to MBR.
Enter `w` for writing to MBR partition.
Enter `y` to finalize and exit.
`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

This time, when you select "Ubuntu" when booting from the pen drive, wait for around one minute until the graphic screen shows up (coz there's a blank screen that persists for quite long). Everything works fine then.

Comment: There  is no option "y" (in the final line) with Ubuntu 22.03 - should this be q (quit without saving) or w (write table to disk and exit)? Debug output suggests not the latter.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for sharing. I no longer use Ubuntu, so I can't check to confirm. Please feel free to add an answer or edit my answer to add a few sentences after my answer, that could help other people who reach this page.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by the fact that your laptop does not support UEFI.

Converting the USB drive partition table from GPT to MBR may help in that case.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1905491/comments/8