# Ubuntu 22.04 installation hangs

Tags: system-installation, usb, 22.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC via an USB live-stick, but the installation hangs right from the beginning. After I select "Install or try Ubuntu" from GRUB the lines
"*...[sdb] No Caching mode page found*" and "*...[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through*" appear and then the installation hangs.

My PC is a bit old and I had to convert my USB live-stick partition to MBR as described here: [can not install from usb with error cannot find grub_platform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288476/can-not-install-from-usb-with-error-cannot-find-grub-platform).
Before I got also the "*error cannot find grub_platform*"-error.

**My system:**

1. Mainboard: Gigabyte Technology X58A-UD7
2. CPU: i7 920
3. GPU: GeForce GTX 970
4. HD: Samsung SSD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Pilot6: Unfortunately not. I red a description explaning the boot-process (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Booting) found through your link. And it seems to me that my bootloader does not find the kernel and the initrd. It might be due to the reason that my PC is quite old. I think it has no UEFI,...

Comment: The idea is to boot with nomodeset.

Comment: Or use the new "with safe graphics" option.

Comment: @Pilot6: With the option nomodeset I was able to install Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately, when I now start my newly installed system, it  boots into a black screen. Therefore, at startup I entered Grub, pressed the "e"-button and replaced "quite splash" with "nomodeset" but the black screen remained. By pressing combinations of "crtrl" + "alt" + "F1, F2, F6, F7" I could enter tty (CLI) and login. There I have got stocked now. What to do now, to load the GUI and which settings should be made till it Ubuntu works properly?

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6: I followed the instruction to install Nvidia drivers: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux. I entered "ubuntu-drivers devices" and the recommended driver by Ubuntu is the correct one, when double-checking with Nvidia-website. Then I entered: "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" but no installation was triggered. Instead I got the following message: "All the available drivers are already installed". Any further hints?

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I tried the solution stated in the following link: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-black-screen-solution but it did not work. I think, when selecting recovery mode at grub, than "safe graphics" are selected for the boot process. Unfortunately ,I again ended up in a black screen. Any further hints?

Comment: Unless you're dual-booting with Windows **11** you can now disable Secure Boot in UEFI and that should be all you need.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I am not dual-booting. The only operation system on my PC is Ubuntu 22.04. I think my PC has no UEFI, because the mainboard is about 15 years old.

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu 22.04 installer frankly sucks. They mixed it--for some idiotic reason--with the try option. I can't get the installer past the language selection and I've installed Ubuntu hundreds of times.