# Ubuntu 22.04 freezing when installing from USB, freezing after "Reached target ZFS Startup target"

Tags: boot, usb

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer ES15 (ES1-533-C2LP) using a Flash drive that has been setup with Rufus using the basic (/recommended) settings.

These are the steps I do:
I plug in the USB, and let it boot into it. Then i get the screen where you can choose from the list:

1. Try or install Ubuntu*
2. OEM Install (manufacturers)
   and the other ones (forgot what they were named).

When I select Option 1 (Try or install Ubuntu*) it restarts, and goes to the boot screen where I can see the ACER logo, with the logo of Ubuntu at the bottom and also seeing the spinner.
The spinner spins for around 30 or so seconds, and after that it just freezes.
When I pressed `F12` when it was spinning, it keeps freezing after the following text: `Reached target ZFS Startup target`. When I've restarted the laptop by shutting it down using the power button, and do all these steps again, it keeps freezing on `Reached target ZFS Startup target`.

I've also tried installing Windows using the same USB stick, this **does** work, without any issues. I've tried different USB ports (all of them) and it was all the same. It just keeps going back to `Reached target ZFS Startup target`. I've also tried setting `nomodeset` in the grub, but this didn't work either.

Does anybody know how this can potentially be fixed, and what I would have to do for it?

**Edit:** I am able to boot into Kali Linux. I’ve tried installing Ubuntu and Lubuntu too, but those last 2 don’t work, they keep freezing on something, not only on `Reached Target: ZFS Startup target`. Kali Linux is of course not the fix, but at least it works…

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when loading Ubuntu 22 from USB on an ASUS TUF i7 & 3060 GPU.  The ASUS logo appeared with the spinning wheel for 30 seconds or so then froze after that.

On boot, I tried "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" which worked and allowed me to install Ubuntu 22.

Credit goes to @ChanganAuto comment on
[Ubuntu 22.04 installation hangs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424978/ubuntu-22-04-installation-hangs)